# How to pass cache key using StringBuilder method?

Tags: java, spring-boot

Trying to pass the below key value as method using string builder, Refer the method cacheKey, but I am getting error as **The value for annotation attribute Cacheable.key must be a constant expression**

// original code

```
  @Cacheable(value = SETTINGS_CACHE,  key = cacheKey(CACHE_MEMBERSHIP_STATUSES))
```

// tried code

```
 @Cacheable(value = SETTINGS_CACHE, key = "'" + CACHE_MEMBERSHIP_STATUSES + "'")


// method
 protected String cacheKey(String key) {   
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        sb.append(STR_APOSTROPHE);
        sb.append(key);
        sb.append(STR_APOSTROPHE);
        

        return sb.toString();
        
    }
```

Comment: the error tells you exactly what the problem is. You can't dynamically build that value

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `spel` to dynamically invoke the method that creates the cache key. Check the following example:

```java
@Component
public class CacheNameCreator {

    public String createCacheKey(String key) {
        return "'" + key + "'";
    }

}
```

And the use the annotation like so:

```java
@Cacheable(value = "some_cache", key = "#{cacheNameCreator.createCacheKey(\"some-key\")}")
```